# Wordpress get_the_category() is returning stuff I don't want

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Wordpress's `get_the_category()` in `archive.php` file while displaying category slug url is returning array of two categories, one different, not associated with 'aktuality-blog' category I use slug for.

Here is `var_dump( get_the_category() );`

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(WP_Term)#4190 (16) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Aktuality"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(9) "aktuality"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(8) "category"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["count"]=>
    int(18)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    int(2)
    ["category_count"]=>
    int(18)
    ["category_description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(9) "Aktuality"
    ["category_nicename"]=>
    string(9) "aktuality"
    ["category_parent"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(WP_Term)#4188 (16) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(30)
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Blog"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(14) "aktuality-blog"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(30)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(8) "category"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    int(30)
    ["category_count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["category_description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(4) "Blog"
    ["category_nicename"]=>
    string(14) "aktuality-blog"
    ["category_parent"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

I expect just array 1 to be array 0, not category actuality there. I can have work around by inserting arrays[1] category int get_posts's $arg.

I don't want workarounds, but solid solution, that would work also on different categories if they ware created, just normal archive, that where I get on category slug, I can simply browse it trought native pagination and so on, not workaround where I will in the end have to rewrite whole cms.

Comment: Are you working in default WP theme?

Comment: Nope, writing custom... No changes to function at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in Wordpress you can have multiple categories associated with a given post.

So what you are experiencing is a normal behavior, you avoid this by simply selecting only one category for the posts you want.

So here is a few things you can do

**Exclude a category from a main posts query.**

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1,-1347' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

**Loop through categories and select the important one for the current context**

```
foreach(get_the_category() as $term){
    if($term->slug == 'aktuality'){ 
        // do something
    }
}
```

**Maybe this?**

Install Yoast Plugin to allow for a primary category or use the forked code independent of the plugin down here.

> https://joshuawinn.com/using-yoasts-primary-category-in-wordpress-theme/

Forked code (didnt personally test it)

```
<?php 
// SHOW YOAST PRIMARY CATEGORY, OR FIRST CATEGORY
$category = get_the_category();
$useCatLink = true;
// If post has a category assigned.
if ($category){
    $category_display = '';
    $category_link = '';
    if ( class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term') )
    {
        // Show the post's 'Primary' category, if this Yoast feature is available, & one is set
        $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( 'category', get_the_id() );
        $wpseo_primary_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
        $term = get_term( $wpseo_primary_term );
        if (is_wp_error($term)) { 
            // Default to first category (not Yoast) if an error is returned
            $category_display = $category[0]->name;
            $category_link = get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id );
        } else { 
            // Yoast Primary category
            $category_display = $term->name;
            $category_link = get_category_link( $term->term_id );
        }
    } 
    else {
        // Default, display the first category in WP's list of assigned categories
        $category_display = $category[0]->name;
        $category_link = get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id );
    }
    // Display category
    if ( !empty($category_display) ){
        if ( $useCatLink == true && !empty($category_link) ){
        echo '<span class="post-category">';
        echo '<a href="'.$category_link.'">'.htmlspecialchars($category_display).'</a>';
        echo '</span>';
        } else {
        echo '<span class="post-category">'.htmlspecialchars($category_display).'</span>';
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: can i have a category independent of the post for search?

Comment: @maztt The category item is a just term that you then associate post with. So in theory you should be able to do a category term and on that category page call the hook `pre_get_posts` to change the query.